# get variable product attributes in cart page woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to display the attributes selected by the user on the cart page in WooCommerce

I tried to get attributes from the variable product but could not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem as follows

```
if ($_product->get_attributes()){
 foreach ($_product->get_attributes() as $key => $val) { ?>
  <p><?= wc_attribute_label($key) ?> : <span> <?= $val ?></span></p>
  <?php }
  }?>
```

you can get **attributes** from ***$_product***